# sendmail fail to deliver mail on gmail

Tags: linux, smtp, gmail, ubuntu-12.04, sendmail

I am using sendmail on ubuntu to send the mail from my server.
I am able to deliver the mails on my domain myid@mydoamin.com but unable to get it on myid@gmail.com .

When I checked the mail.log file is showing "stat=Service unavailable" for myid@gmail.com and "stat=Sent (t7D7KdJa029551 Message accepted for delivery" for myid@mydomain.com.

I have two another server and have done the same thing for sendmail and those servers is working very well.

I have proper hostname and host name entry in /etc/hosts file.

What would be the issue?

Comment: Do you send new messages or forward received messages? Anti-spam at receiving host may react differently.

Comment: I am sending new message

Comment: Could you post complete log file entries?